# Amazon SES Sending email with attachments

Tags: amazon-web-services, salesforce

I am trying to send mails with attachment by using Amazon SES

```
    HttpRequest httpReq = new HttpRequest();
    httpReq.setMethod('POST');
    httpReq.setEndpoint('https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com');
    Blob bsig = Crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA256', Blob.valueOf(awsFormattedNow), Blob.valueOf(secret));
    httpReq.setHeader('X-Amzn-Authorization','AWS3-HTTPS AWSAccessKeyId='+key+', Algorithm=HmacSHA256, Signature='+EncodingUtil.base64Encode(bsig));
    httpReq.setHeader('Date',awsFormattedNow);

    httpReq.setHeader('From','sample@gmail.com');
    httpReq.setHeader('To','sample@gmail.com');
    httpReq.setHeader('Subject','Hello');

    httpReq.setHeader('Accept-Language','en-US');
    httpReq.setHeader('Content-Language','en-US');
    httpReq.setHeader('Content-Type','multipart/mixed;boundary=\"_003_97DCB304C5294779BEBCFC8357FCC4D2\"');
    httpReq.setHeader('MIME-Version','1.0');

//    httpReq.setHeader('Action','SendRawEmail');


    String email = 'Action=SendRawEmail';

    email += '--_003_97DCB304C5294779BEBCFC8357FCC4D2 \n Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii" \n Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable \n';

    email +='Hi Andrew.  Here are the customer service names and telephone numbers I promised you.';

    httpReq.setBody(email);
    System.debug(httpReq.getBody());
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse response = http.send(httpReq);
```

I am getting error like

```
<AccessDeniedException>
  <Message>Unable to determine service/operation name to be authorized</Message>
</AccessDeniedException>
```

Kindly please help me where i am doing wrong .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take another look at the documentation.  There are several issues with your code.

SES expects an HTTP POST with all of the parameters strung together consistent with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` POST requests.

Your HTTP request needs to be `Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, not `multipart/mixed...` -- that's part of the raw message you're trying to send.

You are mixing up things that should be in the body, and setting HTTP request headers, instead.  For example, these are also incorrect:

```
httpReq.setHeader('From','sample@gmail.com');
httpReq.setHeader('To','sample@gmail.com');
httpReq.setHeader('Subject','Hello');
```

These should go in the request body, not in the HTTP request headers.  Also, the values are urlencoded.  From the example code:

```
Action=SendEmail
&Source=user%40example.com
&Destination.ToAddresses.member.1=allan%40example.com
```

The line breaks were added for clarity.

Your interests might be best served by trying to successfully send a simple e-mail, first, and then later attempting to modify your code to support attachments, because you have numerous errors that will need to be corrected before this code will work properly.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/query-interface-requests.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_SendRawEmail.html

Comment: Hi @michael , i realized the error after seeing this post, i am unable to understand which goes into headers and which are not and how to set boundary(headers or body). can you please give me some sample code to send raw message without attachments, so that i will be more clear. Thanks for your response

Comment: Hi @Michael, i am done it. Thanks a lot for your valuable suggessions,helped me alot